# How to pass media queries with jQuery CSS method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I have a media query like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
}
```

I need to change the style like:

```
 $( "#heightSet" ).change(function() {
              var choice = $(this).val();
              if (choice == "50"){
                $(".navbar-nav > li > a").css({"padding-top":"15px","padding-bottom":"15px"});
              }
                if (choice == "60"){
                $(".navbar-nav > li > a").css({"padding-top":"20px","padding-bottom":"20px"});
              }
});
```

How can I take care of the `@media (min-width: 768px)` on the `.CSS()` so the code is affected only on that specific view port?

Comment: Add rules to your CSS involving those height choices and a set of classes to choose between them instead of directly modifying the styles of DOM elements.

Comment: Hi Pointy, thanks for comment but what do you mean by "Add rules to your CSS involving those height choices.."?

Comment: See the answer given by @isherwood . You can't involve media queries with per-element style rules; there's just no mechanism for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
.my-class-15 {padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px;}
.my-class-20 {padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;}

$("#heightSet").change(function () {
    var choice = $(this).val();

    if (choice == "50") {
        $(".navbar-nav > li > a").addClass('my-class-15');
    }
    if (choice == "60") {
        $(".navbar-nav > li > a").addClass('my-class-20');
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle, but it's not very useful without your HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nf5tP/